# Using Chrome and Fiddler showed strange requests - what is it?

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

For one of my projects I am using Fiddler ( http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ ) to trace my http request. I have noticed some strange calls (screenshot) to some weird URLs whenever I start Chrome (Version 23.0.1271.1 dev-m) .

I have disabled all extensions, because this was my first idea - the calls persist.
Any ideas what these calls (screenshot 3,4,5) are?

[image: Strange Chrome calls]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is OK. Google Chrome at startup makes 3 request to random domains. The goal of the requests is to determine if you’re currently on a network that intercepts and redirects requests for nonexistent hostnames. You can read more in that article https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup.